# Mixed content, combining http and https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have wordpress web and now I install the SSL Let´s encrypt certificate. Now when i access the web, https working, but i dont have the green lock -> secured.

When i press F15 on homepage, i got 6 errors -> mixed content https and http, logo src= is running on http (wp-content/*) and other 5 images comming from other web on http.

Is there some way to solve this via .htacces? Or some good performing (low load usage) wp plugin? Because I cant find in the code where is all 6 image paths...

Or what do you recommend? I find that logo is on 30 line in index.. but in index I have 5 lines with including 5 files.. then again including files.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to force all traffics to https with .htaccess, it may help you.
You should replace example.com with your website domain name.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[Source](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/how-to-force-https-using-the-htaccess-file)

Comment: not working :/ i try to put it to .htacces and then F5 reload, and not working

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like the [Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) plugin. Nice and lightweight and works really well. I have seen some "stubborn" files though sometimes elude its clutches, and the [Insecure Content Fixer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) plugin has really good results.

Alternatively you can aggressively force all `src` attributes to `https` using an output buffer and replacing them, effectively doing a "Run time find & replace".

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so_50976235_force_src_ssl' );
function so_50976235_force_src_ssl(){
    ob_start( function($buffer){
        $buffer = str_ireplace( 'src="http://', 'src="https://', $buffer );
        $buffer = str_ireplace( "src='http://", "src='https://", $buffer );

        return $buffer;
    });
}
```

Note: With the function above it will aggressively replace all `src` attributes with secure protocols, and I use both `src='` and `src="` because some plugins will load in attributes with single or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

My method (please comment if you disagree)...

Your Wordpress install is setup for http:// and as such all references to images and links are to http://

To fix this you can use the plugin [Better Search and Replace](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) to search your entire db for your old address eg http://example.com and replace with https://example.com

Make your you backup your DB first and when running the search you need to tick the box to include guid's

Finally you need to create a rule in your .htaccess to rewrite and traffic to http:// to https:// as well as redirect to your preferred address www. or non www.

This tool will help you with the .htaccess code https://www.htaccessredirect.net/